# How to check a change of dns server in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns

I will need some help on on the topic.

I want to create a script to check when a dns is changed , 
when a user switches network providers.

I tried running
**dns.getServers()** in the node cli
it returned the dns of the present network

I made a switch to another network provider without exiting the node cli 
executed **dns.getServers()** again
it return the dns of the previous provider

How can one fix this.

Comment: I tried looking in the node.js source code.  `dns.getServers()` ends up calling [native code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/cares_wrap.cc#L1196) that calls the native function `ares_get_servers()`.  So, the answer apparently lies in the native implementation of `ares_get_servers()`, but that's as far as I got.  Probably need to find some way to flush DNS server internals/cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem.
Thanks to @jfriend00 for the native code issue.

the best way for now to get node to detect you dns when a change occur is to get a dependence resolvmon

npm install resolvmon

it work like a charm.

but if anyone still have a better approach, i will like to know and learn.